# How do I see a MariaDB Virtual Formula once the Table is Created?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I Created a table below.

```
CREATE TABLE product ( 
productname VARCHAR(25),  
price_eur DOUBLE, 
xrate DOUBLE, 
price_usd DOUBLE AS (price_eur*xrate) VIRTUAL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)
```

How Can I View the price_usd Formula after I Created the Table? I use phpMyAdmin and all it shows that it's a VIRTUAL and a DOUBLE.

Thank You for Your Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find which columns are virtual with this query

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name 
  from information_schema.columns 
 where extra='virtual'
```

In order to see the formula you need to issue the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` command; it doesn't seem like the MariaDB team has put virtual-column formulae into the `information_schema` yet, sigh.